# SDL_Loadbitmap as static member in a class

Tags: c++, oop, static, sdl

I'm making a game in SDL, and assigning objects with a bitmap, i wanted to try static, but i get an error that the declaration is incompatible. What am i missing?

my class cpp

```
SDL_Surface Enemy::sprite =  SDL_LoadBMP("ship.bmp");
```

my class h

```
class Enemy
{
   public:
    static SDL_Surface *sprite;
};
```

Comment: Your definition is missing a `*`.

Comment: SDL_LoadBMP returns an address, therefore i need sprite not *sprite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by user786653, you are missing an asterix in your declaration,

```
SDL_Surface* Enemy::sprite =  SDL_LoadBMP("ship.bmp");
```

should be correct. As is, the type of the variable in your class header is a pointer to an SDL_Surface, but the static declaration in your cpp file is for a straight SDL_Surface.